# jQuery: click function exclude children.

Tags: jquery

Trying to wrap my head around the jQuery ".not()" function, and running into a problem. I would like to have the parent div to be "clickable" but if a user clicks on a child element, the script is not called.

```
$(this).not(children()).click(function(){
   $(".example").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

the html:

```
<div class="example">
   <div>
      <p>This content is not affected by clicks.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 214, accepted):

To do this, stop the click on the child [using .stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(".example").click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut("fast");
}).children().click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

This will stop the child clicks from bubbling up past their level so the parent won't receive the click.

`.not()` is used a bit differently, it filters elements out of your selector, for example:

```
<div class="bob" id="myID"></div>
<div class="bob"></div>

$(".bob").not("#myID"); //removes the element with myID
```

For clicking, your problem is that the [click on a child bubbles up to the parent](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), not that you've inadvertently attached a click handler to the child.

Comment: thanks nick, I do not think that this is what i was looking for. I am sorry that I was not clear in my question. 

I want the entire div.example to fadeOut, only when the parent element is clicked, not when the child div is clicked. The reason for this is I would like the user to be able to click on the paragraph text and not have the text fadeOut. If the user clicks on the outer div (parent div), then everything will fade out.

Comment: @superUntitled - Thanks for the clarification...answer's updated to do this, give it a try.

Comment: this is problematic when I have other events tied to the elements (onsubmit of the child elements doesn't work anymore for some reason)

Comment: @Asaf - use `e.stopPropagation();` instead of `return false;` for that case.

Comment: You can also use `}).find('.classes-to-ignore').click(function(e) {` to pick specific child elements

Comment: I don't understand why you tell him to use `e.stopPropagation()` and then use `return false` instead. `return false` is equivalent to `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation()` so it might have unexpected side-effects.

Comment: @NickCraver What if I want to do it reverse? like   <div id="dropdown-menu"> <button> Click Me</button></div> if I use stopPropagation() on the #dropdown-menu then the "Click Me" button gets dumb. How to avoid it getting dumb? Normally can be solved using $(document).on('click','dropdown-menu',function(){e.stopPropgation();}); But then when loaded dynamically it's dire situation. the solution  does not work anymore! What can I do? [See my question please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812137/how-to-handle-bootstrap-2-default-dropdown-menu-and-jquery-stoppropagation-issue)

Comment: Doing a `return false` actually causes things like form elements to stop working, be warned.

Comment: This is a bad answer, any click event listeners that are attached to the children will be ignored.

Comment: What about you update your answer? You mention that you must use `stopPropagation()` but your answer shows otherwise.

Answer (score 194):

I'm using following markup and had encoutered the same problem:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="abc.html">abc</a></li>
    <li><a href="def.html">def</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here I have used the following logic:

```
$(".nav > li").click(function(e){
    if(e.target != this) return; // only continue if the target itself has been clicked
    // this section only processes if the .nav > li itself is clicked.
    alert("you clicked .nav > li, but not it's children");
});
```

In terms of the exact question, I can see that working as follows:

```
$(".example").click(function(e){
   if(e.target != this) return; // only continue if the target itself has been clicked
   $(".example").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

or of course the other way around:

```
$(".example").click(function(e){
   if(e.target == this){ // only if the target itself has been clicked
       $(".example").fadeOut("fast");
   }
});
```

Comment: I think this is the better solution. It doesn't interfere with the children in any way and it should perform better as it doesn't potentially register thousands of callbacks if there are thousands of children.

Comment: @l2aelba - you should be using `.on("click", ...)` in recent versions of jQuery as `.live()` has been deprecated since v1.7. See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Yes, @Chris I posted on Nov 16 '12 at 10:12

Comment: Sorry, probably didn't need to reference your ID. I added the comment largely for anyone else reading this answer.

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer as it doesn't interrupt any click events on child elements

Comment: This is not the accepted answer but it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 26):

Or you can do also:

```
$('.example').on('click', function(e) { 
   if( e.target != this ) 
       return false;

   // ... //
});
```

Comment: You must to return false, to avoid the click event in the children elements. The revision was wrong

Answer (score 10):

My solution:

```
jQuery('.foo').on('click',function(event){
    if ( !jQuery(event.target).is('.foo *') ) {
        // code goes here
    } 
});
```

Comment: Similar to the solution above yours.

Answer (score 7):

I personally would add a click handler to the child element that did nothing but stop the propagation of the click. So it would look something like:

```
$('.example > div').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: what's the difference between `stopPropagation` and returning false like other answers suggest?

Comment: I believe in this case they’d be functional the same, but I think stop propagation is clearer to the purpose of what’s being done and leaves a better chance of understanding why it’s being done later. But it’s debatable.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. it seems like `stopPropagation` may be cleaner as it won't stop events on child elements from occurring, which may happen with `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Green square is parent and yellow square is child element.

Hope that this helps.

```js
var childElementClicked;

$("#parentElement").click(function(){

  $("#childElement").click(function(){
     childElementClicked = true;
  });

  if( childElementClicked != true ) {

   // It is clicked on parent but not on child.
      // Now do some action that you want.
      alert('Clicked on parent');
   
  }else{
      alert('Clicked on child');
    }
    
    childElementClicked = false;
 
});
```

```css
#parentElement{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:green;
position:relative;
}

#childElement{
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:50px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentElement">
  <div id="childElement">
  </div>
</div>
```