# How to capture jQuery event always on the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".parent").on('click', callback);
```

The problem is that depends on the styling (specifically where the mouse pointer clicks) the click event is fired on `.child` or `.parent` depending on the location of the mouse.

Is there a way of getting the event always from `.parent` even if it was clicked on `.child`?
How I used to solve this issue is by checking the id or class of `$(event.target)` and if it was not the `.parent` then I would do `$(event.target).parent()` but I need a solution that works for several scenarios rather than a fix.

Comment: in on click function have u try this
    event.preventDefault()

Comment: Similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457246/jquery-click-function-exclude-children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`. The `event.currentTarget` property is the current DOM element within the event bubbling phase, and is typically equal to `this`.

`event.currentTarget`  - The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.

`event.target` - The DOM element that initiated the event.

```
$(".parent").on('click', callback);

function callback(event){

    alert( event.currentTarget === this );
}
```

fiddle for `event.currentTarget` - [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Du45/3/)

fiddle for `event.target` - [**FIDDLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Du45/4/)

Comment: You answer is correct (same for @horssujet) ! Thank you I just have to use `$(event.currentTarget)`

Comment: Can you update your answer? noting that people just have to use `$(event.currentTarget)`

Answer (score 1):

Check if target is currentTarget.

```
if (event.target == event.currentTarget)
```

http://jsbin.com/jehuz/1/edit

Javascript :

```
$(".parent").on('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target == event.currentTarget) return;

    $(event.currentTarget);
}
```

Sample javascript :

```
$(".parent").on('click', function (event) {
    $("p.1").text("target : "+event.target.className);
    $("p.2").text("currentTarget : "+event.currentTarget.className);
    if (event.target == event.currentTarget) {
        $(this).toggleClass("a");
    }
});
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lddLv.png]

Comment: Thank you! All I need is to do this: `$(event.currentTarget)` can you update you answer?

Comment: ` if (this == event.currentTarget) return;` I think this is wrong.. we don't even need to do a check no?

Comment: @JadJoubran if (this == event.currentTarget) it is right it check the current element and the clicked one. if any doubt regarding this see my fiddle

Comment: yeah but no need to check if this === event.currentTarget because I need both events on the parent and on the child, but I always want to get a revence of the event.currentTarget (the .parent in the example) that's why your solution was correct

Comment: `1` and `2` not valid class names. [What characters are valid in CSS class selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Keep this code as it is:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".parent").on('click', callback);
```

but add:

```
$('.child').click(function() {
   //find the parent of the clild
   var parent = $(this).closest('.parent');
   //if it exists
   if (parent.length > 0)
   {
      //fire the click event, above, thus running 'callback'
      parent.click();
   }
});
```

That said this does sound like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)