# How to remove certain contents from a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<div class="outer">
    Some Text
    <div class="inner">
         .....
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I remove or change the "Some Text" without affecting the inner div?

Comment: Or this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457246/jquery-click-function-exclude-children

Comment: post your code - looks like something like `$('.outer').html("new text");`

Comment: I could just wrap the text in a  span and manipulate that

Comment: `$('.outer').get(0).childNodes[0]`

Comment: please mark anyone as answer if you think it works for you

Comment: I used my answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$('.inner').each(function (){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this.previousSibling);
});
```

Comment: @cookie: thanks, one day I'll learn to stop using tablets/phones for code (or train the spell-check/autocorrect)...