# Bootstrap: Using panel heading to collapse panel body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap v3 Panel with a panel-heading and panel-body. I want a user to be able to click on the panel-heading and it will collapse/expand the panel-body. I am using Bootstrap's Collapse javascript to do this. Here is my markup:

```
<div class="panel panel-default group-panel">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel-body-foobar">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs">Action Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body collapse in" id="panel-body-foobar">
    Some content here. 
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works fine, clicking on the panel heading will collapse/expand the body. However, notice that I also have a button inside the panel heading. When I click that button, it is collapsing/expanding the panel body. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwxea7qn/) if you don't know what I mean.

How can I configure this so that only clicking directly on the panel heading, not any child elements, will trigger the collapsing/expanding?

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/3230/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution is to define my own click handler (rather than using the one Bootstrap sets up automaitcally) which ignores clicks on children:

```
$('.panel-heading[data-toggle^="collapse"]').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(target).collapse('toggle');
}).children().click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457291/1025963) for helping me figure out how to have a jQuery click handler ignore the clicks on children. Note that due to use of `e.stopPropagation();`, this does not disable any click handlers on the children themselves.

Comment: The solution would simply be to stop even propagation from the button in the panel heading, and nothing more: https://jsfiddle.net/mwxea7qn/1/. You don't need to do anything else on `data-toggle` nor `data-target` attributes.

Comment: Indeed, but that requires me to place that line in the click handlers for all children. In my question, I wanted to keep it simple, so I only included a single button, but in my actual project I do have multiple buttons so placing this on the panel-heading seems to make sense.

Comment: You don't have to select by ID. Here's a demonstration that extends my initial point to address the concern you shared above: https://jsfiddle.net/mwxea7qn/2/

Comment: Thanks, now I see what you're saying. Your answer is definitely a valid one.