# Execure Parent div methods and not Child's in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure in my html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I also have two jQuery `click()` actions on each of my classes:

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
    //Methods Set 1
});

$('.child').click(function() {
    //Methods Set 2
});
```

Assume that the css is as simple as it need to be, just to be able to click the divs.

Now my question is the following: how is it possible to set the jQuery action in `.child` class to execute the `Methods Set 2` **BUT NOT** to execute the `Method Set 1` after?

What do I expect to see:

When user click the `.parent` class, then it will only execute the first set of methods that belongs in that action call.

When the user click the `.child` class,  then it will only execute the second set of methods that belongs in that action call.

What happens with my code: when the user click the `parent` class, the first set method is called. **[OK]**

When the user click the `.child` class, first the `Methods Set 2` is execute, then it calls the `Set Method 1` and execute them. **[FAIL]**

What have I tried so far:

A not so simple question for me that kept me far from many ideas I had and forced me to change my plans so many times.

1. I have tried to set [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not) in my `.parent` selector like this:

   ```
   $('.parent').not('.child').click(function() {
       //Methods Set 1
   });
   ```

   But even if I don't get any errors in my console (I use `firebug` in Firefox for debugging logs) I don't get the expected result.
2. I also tried the [`:not()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in my `.parent` class but also didn't get the results I expected.

   ```
   $('.parent:not(.child)').click(function() { /*Methods Set 1 */});
   ```

Comment: The accepted answer to this question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457246/jquery-click-function-exclude-children

Comment: @ShaunScovil I'm sorry not as I expected.

Comment: What I was getting at was the difference between event.target and currentTarget, which is better explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget

Comment: see my edited answer. sorry for mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some help from  [noc2spam ツ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437261/noc2spam-%E3%83%84)  who redirect me to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457291/4108694) answer I found the way to do it.

What I actually wanted is [`stopPropagation()` Event](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on `.parent` class.
So my code will be as bellow:

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
    //Methods Set 1
}).children().click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

**Clarification**

From jQuery Api Page:

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

So, as I use Event bubbling the event handler of `.child` will execute first and then comes the event handler of `.parent`, which is ignored as I use `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
               / \
---------------| |-----------------
| parent       | |                |
|   -----------| |-----------     |
|   |child     | |          |     |
|   -------------------------     |
|        Event BUBBLING           |
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

Use stopPropagation() function. [see here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
//Methods Set 1
});

$('.child').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();  
//Methods Set 2
});
```

Comment: oops. sorry, my mistake. copy+paste function name againg

Comment: I found the same way so I posted my own answer which came after yours as I didn't saw it from editing. I also add some explain. Sorry for that.... +1