# jQuery ignore parent?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple html, a div which contains some html and a delete link:

```
<div class="item">
I am a text this section can contain a lot of html and stuff...
<a class="del_button" href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

here is the jQuery part:

```
$(".item").click(function(){
alert("Item clicked");
});

$(".del_button").click(function(){
alert("DELETE clicked");
});
```

If I click on the "Delete" link, two messageboxes are shown, "Item clicked" and "DELETE clicked" - How can I suppress the "Item clicked" alert if I click the delete button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery stop child triggering parent event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$(".del_button").click(function(e){
    alert("DELETE clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: "event" should "e" or "e" should be "event".

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".del_button").click(function(e){

alert("DELETE clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

you can check from here http://jsfiddle.net/tqT2u/