# jQuery not selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with jQuery selectors:

```
$("ul.questions li").not(".title, .content").click().live('click', function(){
        $(".inspector").slideToggle();
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
               $(this).removeClass("selected");
        } else {
               $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
});
```

In that code it works if I remove `.not(".title, .content")`. but if I add it, it just doesn't gets the click. I use `live` because usually the elements are added through `.append()`, except some ones. This is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/88w8N/ . Basically I want to handle click on the li element, but not if it clicks on the `.title` and `.content` divs. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [stop jQuery from triggering an event attached to the parent when the child is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event).

You need to use jQuery's [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function, which

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

In your code specifically: http://jsfiddle.net/88w8N/21/

```
$("ul.questionssel li div, ul.questionsnosel li div").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

#### UPDATE

To fix your "live" issue, try the following modification: http://jsfiddle.net/88w8N/25/

```
$("ul.questionssel").on('click', 'li', function() {

    //$(".inspector").slideToggle();
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
});

$("ul.questionsnosel").on('click', 'li', function() {
    //$(".inspector").slideToggle();
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
});

$("ul.questionssel li div, ul.questionsnosel li div").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Okay, for some reason I can't get `.on()` working with my code, but the jsFiddle, which basically is the same works perfectly... :/

Comment: jQuery's `.on()` function was introduced in version 1.7. What version are you using?

Comment: I have jQuery v1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.16

Comment: Did you check out my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88w8N/21/)? Because I made an adjustment to the your code as well. Instead of `.click().live('click', function(){`, I'm doing `.on('click', function() {`.

Comment: yeah, but somehow `.on()` doesn't works when I use `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

Try `:not("...")` instead of `.not("...")`

please double-check these links:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I used the selector `$("ul.questions li:not(div .title)")` so I check if it works, but I can still click on the title and the click() action is still being called

Answer (score 0):

You can use not selector instead of not function
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/