# simulating onclick event with javascript

Tags: javascript, click, simulate

What i am trying to do is to put an imagebutton in div which is wider than the button itself and when the outside div is clicked, i want the image button onclick() function to be called. What i expect from below html code is, when i click the button itself, it should alert only "button clicked". when i click the outside div, it should alert "div clicked" first, then "button clicked". The problem is, when i click the div, it alerts: "div clicked" then "button clicked" and then "div clicked" again, in order. When i click the button, it alerts: "button clicked" then "div clicked" then "button clicked" and then "div clicked".

I could not find what i am missing here, any helps?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid red;" onclick="alert('div clicked');(document.getElementById('addButton')).click();">
        <input type="button" onclick="alert('button clicked');"
            id="addButton"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, code formatting was wrong, edited now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event - possible duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've missed is the fact that some events bubble up the document tree triggering all click handlers of parent elements. To stop it, call stopPropagation on the event object.

```
<input type="button" onclick="event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);alert('button clicked');"
        id="addButton"/>
```

(in old IE there is no stopPropagation, you need to set event.cancelBubble=true)

Answer (score 1):

In Internet Explorer, you can simply do

```
myElement.click();
```

However, the W3 standard is a bit more complex.
The following code should work for other browsers:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
myElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

- [document.createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent)
- [Mouse Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent)

See also this question: [How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0):

use window.event.stopPropagation(); like

```
<div style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid red;" onclick="alert('div clicked');(document.getElementById('addButton')).click();">
    <input type="button" value="X" onclick="alert('button clicked');window.event.stopPropagation();"
        id="addButton"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to avoid the event bubbling from Javascript like so :

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickOnDiv(e){
            alert('Div clicked.');
            document.getElementById('addButton').click();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    function clickOnButton(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // This line to prevent event bubbling
        e.stopPropagation() ? e.stopPropagation() : (e.cancelBubble=true);

        alert('Button clicked.');
        return false;
    }


    </script>
    <div id='maDiv' style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid red;">
        <input type="button" value="Click Me !" id="addButton"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function(){
            document.getElementById('addButton').onclick = clickOnButton;
            document.getElementById('maDiv').onclick = clickOnDiv;
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested.. :)

Comment: Also, I refactored your code in order it will be more compliant with DOM Event model level 2..