# How to trigger an event on a parent but not on its child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of html:

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="child></div>
</div>
```

and it looks graphically like this:

```
---------------------------
-                         -
-    #parent              -
-                         -
-         ----------      -
-         -        -      -
-         - #Child -      -
-         -        -      -
-         ----------      -
-                         -
---------------------------
```

How do I trigger an event in jQuery (roll over for example) that will work only when hovering on the `#parent` but **will not work** when hovering on the `#child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)**

question similar to it is [jquery stop child triggering parent event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event)

```
$("#parent").click(function(event){
  //do something with parent

});
$("#child").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think looking into event.stopPropagation would do the trick...

```
$("#someElement").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

If you `return false` from an event handler, it will stop the event from bubbling up to the next ancestor.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/CV76D/

```
$('#outer').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('green');
});

$('#inner').mouseover(function () {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent').on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target === document.getElementById('child')) return false;
    // your code 
})
```

However in my point of view it will be better to resort to `.stopPropagation()`, as others said