# Jquery link only action

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following html code:

```
<a href="/produkt" class="menuTabs">My Catalog 1 <span>(23752)</span></a>
```

JQuery:

```
    $('a.menuTabs', '#subNav').mouseover(function (e) {
...
```

The issue here is that I only want to execute mouseover function when I'm over the words "My Catalog 1" and NOT the "span" selection.
thanks

Comment: Can you alter the HTML and wrap My Catalog 1 into another element?

Comment: This really can't be done reliably without wrapping the text you want the event attached to in it's own element, like a `<span>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just wrapping the text you want to trigger mouseover in an own span?

```
<a href="/produkt" class="menuTabs"><span class="mouseover">My Catalog 1</span> <span>(23752)</span></a>

$('a.menuTabs span.mouseover', '#subNav').mouseover(function (e) {
```

Comment: This is what I would do. Not really necessary to attach a class to the span though, since in this context you can just target the *first* span

Comment: It's not always possible to change layout. However, good fix.

Comment: Of course, it's not always possible to change the layout (e.g. in Chrome extensions), but in most cases it should and he did not mention, that he can't :)

Answer (score 1):

Just check which element is the target of the mouse over

```
$('a.menuTabs', '#subNav').mouseover(function (e) {
    if (e.target != this){
        $('.disp').text('s');
        return;
    }
    $(​'.disp'​​​​).text('a');
}​);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brfLX/

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CZBMS/1/):

```
$('a.menuTabs').mouseover(function (e) {});
$('a.menuTabs > span').mouseover(function (e) {  e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Question same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event).

Comment: Does this actually work? I would think not since the event is bound to the parent

Comment: This is not reliable though, since the parent element can easily wrap around the child element. See for instance if we add a little padding: http://jsfiddle.net/CZBMS/2/

Comment: Yes, in this case we must change layout like in Robin's answer.