# make overhead div tag as not conductive for inferior div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery stop child triggering parent event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event)

I have 2 div tag, parent and children, I want at click on parent div - alert() some. Problem is that: at click in children div, alert() also happening and I want call alert only click on parent div tag area, tell please how to make this? 
this is my html code

```
<div id="out_div" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #090; position:    absolute; z-index: 1">
        <div id="inner_div" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #009; position: absolute; z-index: 2; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">

        </div>
    </div>
```

and js code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

            $("#out_div").on("click", function () {
                alert("asd");
            });

        });
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the `event.target` :

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53TrW/1/)

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $("#out_div").on("click", function ( e ) {
         if (!$(e.target).is(this)){ return; }
         alert("asd");
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, problem is solved