# Have jQuery ignore children on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have the following markup:

```
<ul id="level1">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul id="level2">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically if i hover over level 1, i need it to do something. However when i hover over level2 it is triggering it because that is inside level1. Is there a way of making this only happen if i hover over level1.

An example of what i mean:

http://scottymeuk.in/Netr

The box on the left, is a parent of the box on the right. But i need the something to happen when hovering over the left box (parent), but not the right box (child).

Thank you.

Sorry if i have failed to explain my issue well enough.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Seems that you need `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event might help out

Comment: Can't you just check if `event.target` == `level1` (pseudo code, not sure if it's actually called target or targetElement or whatever)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to call `event.stopPropagation` on the child:

```
$("#parent").on("someevent", function(){
  // do stuff
});

$("#child").on("someevent", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the event from bubbling to the parent.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the event object documentation...

http://api.jquery.com/category/event-object/

`event.stopPropagation();`

is what you need

```
$('#level2').hover)function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops events from triggering in children
},function (e) {}
```

Comment: By the time it's reached `#level1` it's too late; this answer isn't correct.

Comment: sorry typo... meant child element

Answer (score 0):

`$('level1').hover(function(){
if(!IsMouseOver($(this).find(level2)){
do what you want it to do
};
});`

I haven't tested it yet but you get the logic.  is mouse over level1? yes. if it's over level1 and its not over level2 do what I want