# Stopping other events when one event occur

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several events bound to each elements. some times, a parent and a child element both contain click events! There for if I click on the child element, the parent element gets fired too. How can I prevent these events from getting fired using jquery!

Comment: Aloha docs! http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: See this answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/2364639/2454105

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()`

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$("p").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

[`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/):- If you want to prevent other event handler registered in the element from firing too

**or**

[`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):- If you want to prevent only the handlers registered in the parent element