# select child element without selecting parent element

Tags: jquery, css

We are doing logging, we have a header of the website where we are logging anytime it is clicked. We have elements within the element that need logging as well.  Is there a way to only log the child elements when clicked within the header by using jquery `.not()` function or anything?

[**Here is the working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5xp44dt0/)

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div><a class="box blue" href="#">Blue</a></div>
    <div><a class="box red" href="#">Red</a></div>
    <div><a class="box green" href="#">Green</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$('#header').on('click', function() 
    alert('header')
});
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: I want the child elements logged, but not the `#header` logged as well. When a child element is clicked both get logged currently

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery stop child triggering parent event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event)

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5xp44dt0/1/?

Comment: Then your scenario is the easiest to fix. Just use `.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.stopPropagation()` function to stop the bubbling from the children to the parent:

```js
$('#header').on('click', function() {
    alert('header');
});
$('.box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```css
#header { padding:20px; background:yellow; overflow:auto; }
    .box { width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin:0 20px 0 0; }
    .blue { background:blue; }
    .red { background:red; }
    .green { background:green; }
 a { color:white; display:block; text-align:center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
 <div><a class="box blue" href="#">Blue</a></div>
    <div><a class="box red" href="#">Red</a></div>
    <div><a class="box green" href="#">Green</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.stoppropagation` is one way to stop the bubbling up from the child element . other than that you can simply check if the current target element is the one that is clicked.

```
$('#header').on('click', function(e) {
 if(e.target == this){
    alert('header');
 }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xp44dt0/2/)

Comment: Checking target is better because it stop this particular event not all other event like Stoppropagation.

Answer (score 1):

`e.stoppropagation`

```
$('#header').on('click', function() 
    alert('header')
});
$('.box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stoppropagation();
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/