# Exclude Button From Event Listener OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Really simple jquery question here that I have yet to resolve. I have the following html table

```
<table id="table-1">
    <tr>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>
            <button id="btn-1" value="Go"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following event listener for when the table row is clicked

```
$("table-1 tr").on(
   'click',
    function(e){
       if(button was clicked){ 
           //do some stuff 
       } else {
           //do different stuff
       }
    }
);
```

I'd like this event listener to fire whenever the table row is selected, except for when the clicked item is my button. I've been trying to use `:not` and `.not()`, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery stop child triggering parent event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off your example where you want to catch the element type.

```
$("#table-1 tr").on('click', function (e) {
    var elementType = $(e.target).prop('nodeName');
    if (elementType == 'BUTTON') {
        console.log('buttonClick');
    } else {
        console.log(elementType);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymy9cn71/

Comment: This was the best answer to my question & implementation, I actually went with `if(document.activeElement.tagName === 'BUTTON') { //do stuff }`

Answer (score 3):

Use [**event.stopPropagation()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), to prevent event bubbling to the parent elements.

```
$('#btn-1').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you set up an event listener on the button specifically? The most specific rule should apply. So if you click on the row then the row event will fire, if you click on the button then the button event will fire FIRST and then the parent will run. So, you could use a simple variable to check whether the button was checked.

Var gContext;

```
$("#btn-1"). on('click', function() { gContext = true });


$("table-1 tr").on(
   'click',
     function(e){
        if(button was clicke$("table-1 tr").on(
         'click',
         function(e){
               if(gContext === true){ 
               //do some stuff 
               } else {
              //do different stuff
          }
     }
  );d){ 
           //do some stuff 
        } else {
             //do different stuff
        }
      }
   );
```

- did this on my phone, hope it formats correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The following code checks the tag name of the event target to know which part of the `tr` was clicked.

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
  var i = $('table tr').index(this);
  var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
  if (tag === 'button') {
    alert('go #' + i);
  }
  else {
    alert('select row #' + i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td><button>Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td><button>Go</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```