# class getting added to div on click of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to do a simple hide & show of a DOM on click event.I am showing the
loadMenu container on clicking of span#dwnTrigger.
But my problem is even when I am clicking on the div#loadMenu , this div#loadMenu is getting hidden. I am not sure how can this happen as the event is attached to span#dwnTrigger.

```
<span id="dwnTrigger" class="dwnPrint" aria-label="Download" ng-controller="dwnCtrl" > Start
  <div class="dwnCtrl menuContainer ng-hide" id="loadMenu">
    //rest of DOM
  </div>
</span>
```

**Controller**

```
abc.controller('dwnCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.$element = $("#dwnTrigger");
  ($scope.$element).on('click',function() {
    if ($("#loadMenu").hasClass('ng-hide')) {
      $("#loadMenu").removeClass('ng-hide').addClass('ng-show');        
      //rest of code
    }
    else if ($("#loadMenu").hasClass('ng-show')) {
      $("#loadMenu").removeClass('ng-show').addClass('ng-hide')
    }
  })
}]);
```

Comment: can you create codepen for same?

Comment: How did you get `downLoadMenu`, where is it?

Comment: Show us html of those ids and classes

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have edited it and have put the right ids

Comment: it would be even better if you would add css of those clasees

Comment: Anyway maybe try separately `$("#loadMenu").removeClass('ng-hide')`
and then below on the new line `$("#loadMenu").addClass('ng-show');` the same goes for `if else` statement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event is your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called event `propagation/bubbling`. When you click on an element the event propagates through all it's parents. So as the `div#loadMenu` is a child of `span#dwnTrigger` the click on `div#loadMenu` propagates to `span#dwnTrigger` and triggers it's event handler.

You can use 'event.stopPropagation()' to prevent this. You have to bind an click event handler to `div#loadMenu`, capture the event and stop propagation.

```
    $('div#loadMenu').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

For more on `event.stopPropagation()` https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Alternatively you can check which element dispatched the event by `event.target` and act based on that. For example your click handler can be like following

```
    ($scope.$element).on('click',function(event) {
        if($(event.target).closest('#loadMenu').length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        if ($("#loadMenu").hasClass('ng-hide')) {
            $("#loadMenu").removeClass('ng-hide').addClass('ng-show');        
           //rest of code
        }
        else if ($("#loadMenu").hasClass('ng-show')) {
            $("#loadMenu").removeClass('ng-show').addClass('ng-hide')
        }
    })
```

For more on `event.target` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: Thanks. But I even tested it by event.stopPropagation(). But no luck

Comment: Where did you put `event.stopPropagation()`? You have to put it in `div#loadMenu`'s click handler.