# Add custom hyperlink after jquery fullcalendar load on each day & stop prevent / propogation on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, stoppropagation

I am using jquery [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) with ASP.NET MVC.

I have implemented successfully but I want to display a hyperlink after calendar load on each day.

I have set the link as well but I got a problem when I click on it because I have also done the **dayClick** event as well so when I click on the link that click fire dayclick event not the hyperlink.

I want to open new tab on click of that link not the dayclick event.

How should I do this?

Anyone if done help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Here is a [`Code sample`](http://jsfiddle.net/MVDotNet/exmort2j/):

[image]

Comment: Use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Should I give this on the anchor tag that I have used on each day?

Comment: Yes in the click handler of that link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery stop child triggering parent event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event)

Comment: You can create an object which contain id of event as well as href link and on click of event iterate that object compare id and using window.location.href to redirect to the repetid link. it may help you

Comment: @anu still having the same issue

Comment: @Console.log Sir I don't understand what you say?

Comment: @padhiyar do you have event id and url where you want to redirect?

Comment: @Console.log I have link  of href on which I want to redirect the page in new tab not existing page.

Comment: Can you add some code which you have tried in your question. Add relevant html and the click handler of the link

Comment: Where is thehyper link click handler in your code? I am unable to locate it

Comment: @anu it is inside the second function at  $(".fc-day-number"... last third line

Comment: Try my answer. Put it outside this calendar code maybe inside `$(document).ready()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your updated post and comments following should work

```
$(document).on('click','.schedulelink',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MVDotNet/CYnJY/736/)

This will prevent click event on your link to bubble up to its parents.

Read more about [stopPropagation() here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Note: I have added `document` in selector as example, replace with appropriate parent, read more about [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jehofobudi/edit?html,js,output)
.In this demo clicking in box will show alert but clicking on link will open new tab

EDIT:
Since this is not working in your environment(for some reason which you need to figure out), here is an alternate approach. check for the target element in your `dayClick` handler and based on that perform action.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) { 
  if (!$(jsEvent.target).hasClass('schedulelink')) { 
    //do your task
  } 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MVDotNet/CYnJY/737/)

Comment: No you get me wrong I want to open the page on new tab on click of hyperlink now click is not opening the tab it prevents to open because of above code. And I don't want to trigger dayClick event on click of hyperlink as well.

Comment: Check the demo in my edited answer. There might be some other error in your code. Check your console, are you getting any error when you click the link. Put some `console.log()` in the function I posted and check if it is being printed

Comment: Yes exactly the same what I wanted thanks. Can you explain me how it not triggered back event in little bit explanation?

Comment: Read about [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in the jquery docs. This fucntion prevents the current event to bubble up to DOM tree.

Comment: No no no sorry it remains the same. it calles the dayclick event.

Comment: I want to stop calling the dayclick event may be not stoppropogation.

Comment: Have you checked your console? As suggested earlier put some console.log in this handler and check response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131686/discussion-between-padhiyar-and-anu).