# How to control click event of <li> conditionally?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a *ul* tag and several *li* tags inside that. When I click on a *li* some action is occurs using J*query* click event. For each *li* the action is different.

Then I added a text box into each *li*. When ever I click on the text box to enter something the *li* click event gets triggerd.

**How do I prevent *li* click event when I am clicking in the text box?**

**HTML code:**

```
<ul id="myul">
    <li id="myli">

        <div>
            // some codes

            <span> 
                // some codes
            </span>

            <input type="text" id="myTextbox" />

            // some codes                                                         
        </div>
    </li>

    // other li tags
</ul>
```

**JQuery click event:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.myli', function (evt) 
        // my actions    
});
```

Comment: what is selecteditem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli

Refer This question..

Comment: @guradio I think he copy paste the code and type wrongly

Comment: I typed it mistakely when copying from my code

Comment: @BrockJames duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event

Answer (score 4):

maybe you have to try j query method which is  `e.stopPropagation();` here is a code

**The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.**

```
 $("input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

here is a link for more [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_stoppropagation)

Answer (score 2):

you should use an js event `e.stopPropagation(); ,which might be help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, It easy like this:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.myli', function (evt){
 console.log('.myli')
 });
 $("#myTextbox").click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 console.log("myTextbox");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myul">
    <li id="myli" class="myli">
        <div>
            <span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="myTextbox" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the click is coming from input text box or not.

try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.myli', function (evt) 
    // hear check if textbox
    if (evt.target.id == "myTextbox") {
         return; 
    }


    // my actions    
});
```

If click is from text box, then rest of the code does not load

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myul li").click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).attr("type") != "text"){
   alert("Li is clicked");
  }
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myul">
    <li id="myli" style="background-color:#efefef;">
  <div>
      some codes1<br/>

        <span> 
             some codes 2 <br/>
        </span>



  <input type="text" id="myTextbox" />  <br/>

                 some codes 3  <br/>
            </div>
    </li>

    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the same scenario that you seek and then used jQuery to stop the event of the parent on child.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('cars').on('click', '.car1', function() {
    alert('Li clicked');
  });

  $(".car1 input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JQuery Issue with propagation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="cars">
    <li class="car1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="click me">
    </li>

    <li class="car2">
      car2
    </li>

    <li class="car3">
      car3
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now if you  click on text car1, the event is triggered, but on clicking the text box, event does trigger anymore.
Hope this will help you.[image]

On clicking the text box, the event will no longer trigger.So the child event will not fire an event any more.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where from the click is coming, use following code :-

```
$('body').on('click', '#myli', function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'input') {
        return;
    }
    // Your Action    
});
```

If click comes from input, then no action is performed

Answer (score 0):

Like [Alpesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2857556/alpesh-jikadra) mentioned event.stopPropagation() should be the right way. I am not sure if "click" or "focus" or maybe both need to be stopped but i wanted to mention that there is a way to stop propagation by using css. Propery "pointer-events".

Maybe it works for your case with a textbox.

[Checkout](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) in your handler to tell which element triggered the event.

```js
$('#myli').click(function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="myli">
    <span>Click me</span>
    <input placeholder="Click me"/>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cfillion Have you read the query what he is facing? He want proper answer not alternate solution.

Comment: @NarendraSolanki Do you mean I should have added the actual check to test whether `evt.target` is the input to the code example?

Comment: Yes exactly Cfillion

Comment: Ah ok. I thought it was a good idea to just point in the right direction and let the reader do the last finishing touch (instead of 100% spoon-feeding the answer). I'll write more complete examples next time.