# How to ignore click listening on child elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple div with one element:

```
<div id="drop-zone">
    <input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple">
</div>
```

When I click on `#drop-zone` I want to trigger `input` manually. I'm trying like this:

```
jQuery('#drop-zone:not(input)').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('input[type="file"]').trigger('click')
})
```

The main problem is that I'm getting an endless loop of clicks as my manual click trigger listener on parent element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery stop child triggering parent event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364629/jquery-stop-child-triggering-parent-event)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the element clicked was the `drop-zone` by checking the `id` of the `target`. When `jQuery` emulates an event it will pass the same `this` reference but will not pass the event, so just check if the event is set.

```js
$("#drop-zone").click(function(event) {
  if (this.id === "drop-zone" && event.originalEvent) {
    $("#drop-zone>input").trigger("click");
  }
})
```

```css
#drop-zone {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-zone">
  <input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple">
</div>
```

You could also just trigger the event manually.

```js
$("#drop-zone").click(function(event) {
  if (this.id === "drop-zone") {
    $("#drop-zone>input")[0].click();
  }
})
```

```css
#drop-zone {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-zone">
  <input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple">
</div>
```

Comment: as I said before - `jQuery(this).find('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');` triggers parent

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```js
var x_m = 0;
var y_m = 0;
$('#drop-zone').click(function(event) {
  var mtarget = document.elementFromPoint(x_m, y_m);
  if (mtarget.id === "drop-zone") {
    var input = $(this).find('input[type="file"]');
    var h = false;
    if ($(input).is(":visible")) {
      input.hide();
    } else {
      input.show();
      h = true;
    }
    console.log("You clicking, the #drop-zone, input.visible =>", h);
  } else { 
    console.log("You clicking the input.");
  }
})
$('body').mousemove(function(evt){
    x_m = evt.pageX;
    y_m = evt.pageY;
});
```

```css
#drop-zone {
  height: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #8b5fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-zone">
  <input type="file" style="display: none; background: green;" multiple="multiple">
</div>
```