# Exclude children from clicking jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a modal container that includes a mini-cart. When the cart is clicked, I want to hide the chat. Currently, it works when clicking on 'mfp-container' and 'x,' but I don't want the chat to appear when clicking on the 'mfp-content' class(children of 'mfp-container').

```js
isChatHidden = false;

$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function() {
  $(".icon-shopping-cart").click(function() {
    $(".chaport-container").hide();
    isChatHidden = true;
  });

  $(".mfp-close, .mfp-container:not(.mfp-content)").click(function() {
    if (isChatHidden == true) {
      $(".chaport-container").show();
      isChatHidden = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mfp-container">
  <div class="mfp-content off-canvas-cart">
    <div>cart items</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button title="Close" type="button" class="mfp-close">x</button>
```

or:

```
$(".mfp-close, .mfp-container").click(function () {
  if (isChatHidden == true) {
    if (!$(".mfp-content").length) {
      $(".chaport-container").show();
      isChatHidden = false;
    }
  }
});
```

or:

```
$(".mfp-close, .mfp-container").click(function () {
if (isChatHidden && !$(".mfp-content").length) {
  $(".chaport-container").show();
  isChatHidden = false;
}
});
```

.. not working - chat is still appearing on clicking '.mfp-content'

Thanks for help,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36876862/4248328

Comment: Welcome alench. Happy coding!